# Android - Verifying if a calendar event exists by id

Tags: android, events, calendar

It is possible verifying if an event exists by event_id? I need do something just if an event still exists. It is possible verifying that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to query using the [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

First you have to query the calendar provider to get the id of the calendar which you want to search in and then you could construct a count query for the event id you are targeting

---

Without opening an IDE to check I'd expect that

```
Uri event = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(event, null, null, null);
If (cursor.getCount() == 1) {
  //the event exists?
}
```